# How to check if a toggle has been toggled and then activate an object in response?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, toggle

We are working on a school project with Unity, a new environment for us as well as C# which is a new language for us.

We are having problems with writing scripts for toggle buttons, part of Unity UI. Essentially, we want to check if a toggle button has been clicked and then activate path objects so they become visible.

We are using the `Toggle.interactable` script for the toggle button. We know that you must use `SetActive(true)` to activate the paths if the toggle is clicked but we are not sure what should be used to check if it is.

Answer (score 5):

Toggle emits an event called `onValueChanged` which fires whenever the toggle value is changed. You will listen to this event, check if it has turned to true, and set your gameobject to active. So in the script that will listen for this event we will set up a listener. Modified example from documentation

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    Toggle m_Toggle;

    void Start()
    {
        //Fetch the Toggle GameObject
        m_Toggle = GetComponent<Toggle>();
        //Add listener for when the state of the Toggle changes, to take action
        m_Toggle.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate {
            ToggleValueChanged(m_Toggle);
        });
    }

    //Output the new state of the Toggle into Text
    void ToggleValueChanged(Toggle change)
    {
        //Activate your game object
    }
}
```

Comment: `onValueChanged` afaik also emits the current state so you could actually directly add a listener `onValueChanged.AddListener(ToggleValueChanged)` and `private void ToggleValueChanged(bool isToggle){ someGameObject.SetActive(isToggle);}`

Comment: So I implemented the code and we are getting an error from Unity that says, NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Visual Studio does not show any errors however Unity is saying that the problem is with the onValueChanged.AddListener(ToggleValueChanged) line.

Comment: That means the `GetComponent` call for `Toggle` is failing. If the Toggle is not on the same game object as this script you will have to add a reference to that gameobject to this script and call `GetComponent` on that gameObject instead

Answer (score 0):

Get your toggle button in a script and use `isOn` bool. Use the below script to observe the values at run time.

```
 public Toggle myToggle;

 void Update()
 {
  print("Current Toggle State : " + myToggle.isON);
 }
```